How Can I Apply Visual Studio's Minted Style to Python Listings in Jupyter Notebook Using LaTeX?
I'm looking to replicate the Visual Studio White Modern theme for Python listings in my LaTeX documents, using Jupyter Notebook for the code. I want the output in LaTeX to mirror the clean and modern look of Visual Studio.
I can provide some screenshots to show exactly how I want the design to appear.
Currently, I'm using the following style in my LaTeX setup:
\begin{listing}[!ht]
\begin{minted}[bgcolor=white, 
               linenos,  
               framesep=2mm, 
               breaklines, 
               fontsize=\small]{python}
import sympy as sm
import sympy.physics.mechanics as me

# this is to get nice looking output
sm.init_printing()

# h: cross-section depth [m]
# b: cross-section width [m]
# g: gravity [m/s^2]
# l: length of pendulum [m]
# rho: density of pendulum [kg/m^3]

# constant parameters that define our problem (simple pendulum)
h, b, g, l, rho, tau1, tau2 = sm.symbols('h, b, g, l, rho, tau_1, tau_2')

m = b * h * l * rho  # mass of the pendulum
Izz = m * l**2 / 12  # moment of inertia of the pendulum around the z-axis (both N and A)

# generalized coordinates (time dependent)
q1, q2 = me.dynamicsymbols('q1, q2')

# time variable (used for derivatives)
t = me.dynamicsymbols._t
\end{minted}
\caption{Example of a simple pendulum defined in SymPy and Mechanics}
\label{listing:1}
\end{listing}




enter image description here

enter code here

